# How to push other view controller when open jonkykong/SideMenu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, side-menu

I make `VOIP` app and for side menu, i used `jonkykong/SideMenu` side menu in swift.

I have the following issue :

> 1)open side menu
>
> 2) Any person calling gets that time I push my call view controller
>   but display "Black Screen".

So how to resolve this issue?

Code For push view:-

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
bundle:nil]; CallViewController *Callview =(CallViewController *) 
 [storyboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallViewController"]; 
if(SharedAppDelegate.GlobalContactArray.count > 0) 
{ 
   Callview.ContactArray = SharedAppDelegate.GlobalContactArray; 
} 
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation]; 
transition.duration = 0.3; transition.type = kCATransitionFromLeft; 
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]; 
[navController.view.layer addAnimation:transition 
forKey:kCATransition]; 
[navController pushViewController:Callview animated:NO];
```

if anyone has a solution for that then please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: check this line `UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]; ` is correctly you get the UInavigation controller or not

Comment: @anbu,
i have get following 2 controller in navcontroller.
<__NSArrayI 0x10bab38f0>(
<Dialer.LoginViewController: 0x108bafbc0>,
<Dialer.HomeViewController: 0x102821600>
)